# part of js code wont work in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm programming an input site and want to highlight empty fields. I want to check if they're empty with an if statement and then add the class that Highlights them.

My code:

HTML:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="nav">
<h1 class="tcontent"> Welcome to the Site!<h1>
</div>

<div id="header">
<h2 class="tcontent"> Register now! </h2>
<p class="tcontent"> To register just fill out the form below and click submit </p>
</div>

<div id="name">
    <div class="da">First Name: </div>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="ip" id="input1" placeholder="firstname"><br><br>
    <div class="da">Last Name: </div>
        <input class="ip" type="text" name="lastname" id="input2" placeholder="lastname">
</div>

<div id="email">
    <div class="da">Email: </div>
        <input type="text" name="email"  class="ip" id="input3" placeholder="email"><br><br>
    <div class="da">Email bestaetigen: </div>
        <input class="ip" type="text" name="emailc" id="input4" placeholder="email bestaetigen">
</div>

<div id="pw">
    <div class="da">Passwort: </div>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="ip" id="input5" placeholder="Passwort eingeben">
    <div class="da">Passwort bestaetigen: </div>
        <input type="password" name="passwordc" class="ip" id="input6" placeholder="Passwort bestaetigen">
</div>

<div id="captcha">
    <p style="font-size:25px" class="tcontent">Here is gonna be a <strong>captcha</strong></p>
</div>
    <div id="submit">
    <input type="radio" name="accept" id="check"><p id="checktxtt"> I agree to the 
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Terms and Conditions</a> </p>
    <p id="checktxtb" >All filled out and ready to go?</p>
        <input type="button" onclick="dcc (); pwc (); hi ();" value="Submit" id="button">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var pwc = function () {
    if (document.getElementById('input5').value.length<6) {
    alert("PW too short!");
}
else if(document.getElementById('input5').value!==document.getElementById('input6').value)
    alert("PW do not match!");
};

var dcc = function () {
    if (document.getElementById('input1').value===""||document.getElementById('input2').value==="" ||document.getElementById('input3').value==="" ||document.getElementById('input4').value==="" ||document.getElementById('input5').value==="" ||document.getElementById('input6').value==="")
    alert("Somethings missing!");
};

var hi = function () {
    if($('#input1').val()==="") {
        $('#input1').addClass('hi'); 
    }
};
```

CSS:

class that is supposed to be added:

```
.hi {
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 0.01em;
    margin-right: 15em;
    margin-top: 1.05em;
    float: right;
}
```

JSFiddle doesnt detect a problem with my JS code. However the input field is not highlighted, the class "hi" doesnt seem to be added. 
The other two JS function function fine. 
Did I chose the right conditional?
If something is missing or if something is not clear enough please comment and I will try to clarify.
Any help is much appreciated!

Changed Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="nav">
<h1 class="tcontent"> Welcome to the Site!<h1>
</div>

<div id="header">
<h2 class="tcontent"> Register now! </h2>
<p class="tcontent"> To register just fill out the form below and click submit </p>
</div>

<div id="name">
    <div class="da">First Name: </div>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="ip" id="input1" placeholder="firstname"><br><br>
    <div class="da">Last Name: </div>
        <input class="ip" type="text" name="lastname" id="input2" placeholder="lastname">
</div>

<div id="email">
    <div class="da">Email: </div>
        <input type="text" name="email"  class="ip" id="input3" placeholder="email"><br><br>
    <div class="da">Email bestaetigen: </div>
        <input class="ip" type="text" name="emailc" id="input4" placeholder="email bestaetigen">
</div>

<div id="pw">
    <div class="da">Passwort: </div>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="ip" id="input5" placeholder="Passwort eingeben">
    <div class="da">Passwort bestaetigen: </div>
        <input type="password" name="passwordc" class="ip" id="input6" placeholder="Passwort bestaetigen">
</div>

<div id="captcha">
    <p style="font-size:25px" class="tcontent">Here is gonna be a <strong>captcha</strong></p>
</div>
    <div id="submit">
    <input type="radio" name="accept" id="check"><p id="checktxtt"> I agree to the 
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Terms and Conditions</a> </p>
    <p id="checktxtb" >All filled out and ready to go?</p>
        <input type="button" onclick="dcc (); pwc (); hi ();" value="Submit" id="button">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
border: 2px dotted black;
height: 100px;
width:700px;
display: block;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
margin-top:1em;

}

.tcontent {
margin:auto;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
margin-top:1em;
}

.ip {
float:right;
width:10em;
margin-right:15em;
margin-top:1em;
position: relative; 
}


.arrange {
width:100em;
margin-left:15em;

}
.da {
margin-top:0.9em;
border: none;
float: left; 
position:relative; 
margin-left:13em;
background-color:green;
width:140px;
overflow:hidden;
height:20px;
}

.hi {
border:1px solid red;
margin-right: 15em;
margin-top: 1.05em;
float: right;
}

#check {
width:20px;   
float:left;
margin-top:1.25em;
margin-left:17.0em
}

#checktxtt {
float:right;   
margin-right: 13.5em;

}
#checktxtb {
float:left;   
margin-left: 13.5em;
margin-top: 0.2em;
position:relative;   
}
#button {
float:right;
margin-right:16em;
}
```

JS:

```
var pwc = function () {
if (document.getElementById('input5').value.length<6) {
alert("PW too short!");
}
else if(document.getElementById('input5').value!==document.getElementById('input6').value)
alert("PW do not match!");
};

var dcc = function () {
if (document.getElementById('input1').value==="" ||document.getElementById('input2').value==="" ||document.getElementById('input3').value==="" ||document.getElementById('input4').value==="" ||document.getElementById('input5').value==="" ||document.getElementById('input6').value==="")
alert("Somethings missing!");
};


var hi = function () {

if($('#input1').val()==="") {
    $('#input1').addClass('hi'); 
}
};
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, use jQuery. `$('#input1').val()` not `document.getElementById('input1').value`. Also, if you did debug with the console you'd have seen the error that points to `document.getElementById('input5').value`. Where's the element with the ID of input5?

Comment: if you mentioned jsfiddle, why not add it to your question. also where is the html for inputs 2 - 6?

Comment: @j08691 I am using ´$('#input1').val()´ in the hi function thats the one that doesnt show on site. I am sorry I am new at all this. I included the rest of my html in the question.

Comment: @Banana I included the rest of my html. What exactly do you mean with including jsfiddle? How can I do that?

Comment: @user3466038, i meant create a jsfiddle, click 'save' on the bar on top, and post the link here

Comment: @Banana Ah ok JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/MPNj8/ I already put in the changes mentioned below

Comment: Seems to work fine now that you included the rest of the code http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TfSg4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code was fine without changes.

the only problem was that you didnt set border style, so u set red border with 0.02em width,
but you didnt tell the browser how to draw it.

change your border stuff to `border:1px solid red;` and it will work.

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/az8Uz/

EDIT:

in your updated code you include jQuery like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

this is wrong, because it searches it in your domain.

you need to add `http:` in the beginning of the link:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Now it works on JSFiddle but still not when I run my coden in Firefox over Notepad++. Seems as if I didnt include the right jquery library... Are there any links to online librarys that you could recommend?

Comment: you can find plenty of jQuery links on google, i personally prefer to download it. http://jquery.com/download/ make sure your link is correct and located on topmost of your head code

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas why its not working on my notepad file? My code is exactly the same as:http://jsfiddle.net/5Qeqh/1/ but if I run it from Notepad in Firefox the input field still wont become red...

Comment: hmm, im not sure, never used notepad ++. are you sure you linked everything correctly? can you update your question and post your entire page just copy&paste from notepad ++. add it to the bottom of ur question

Comment: Put everything at the end of my Question. I used a google hosted jquery library as you can see.

Comment: Thanks very much that solved it!! Some people downvoted my question any advice for a newbie on how to ask better questions?

Comment: you are welcomed :) i would advise however, to include all the relevant code and not just parts of it. i recall you referred in your JS to elements which you didnt include the code ...

Comment: Yeah my fault ^^ I think in the future I am just going to link to a jsfiddle with the whole code and reference my problems :) Thanks again for your help, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/5Qeqh/1/

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="ip" id="input1" placeholder="firstname">
<br>
<a href="#" id="check">Check</a>

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {          
    $( "#check" ).click(function() {
         $('input[type=text]').each(function(){          
            var value = $(this).val();
          if (value == ""){
             $(this).addClass("red");
          }
       });
    });    
});

.red{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: I included your code in my file. However the input field remains the same upon clicking "check"... Is the conditional the right one? Or wont it work because of §('#input1').val()==="" ?

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle link? If you compare you only "==", no need for "===".

Comment: My fiddle file: http://jsfiddle.net/MPNj8/ I put your code in and still the input field remains the same